# Creating a ramdisk with lvmvdo persistent across reboot?

Tags: filesystems, lvm, rhel8, ramdisk

I am trying to create a persistent ramdisk with lvmvdo with the below unit file but it does not seem to work.I have not added the `--type vdo` option to the lvcreate command yet ( this is for **RHEL9** )

```
[mukesh@server1 ~]$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/my_lvm.service 
[Unit]
Description=Create and mount LVM logical volume

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'mknod /dev/ram0 b 1 0; \
  pvcreate /dev/ram0; \
  vgcreate my_vg /dev/ram0; \
  lvcreate -n my_lv -L 100M my_vg; \
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/my_vg/my_lv; \
  mount /dev/my_vg/my_lv /mnt/ramdisk'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Ok i made some changes ( i am using `brd` kernel module instead of `mknod`), now ExecStart is working fine but ExecStop does not work.

```
[mukesh@server1 ~]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/my_lvm.service 
[Unit]
Description=Create and mount LVM logical volume

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'pvcreate /dev/ram0; \
  vgcreate my_vg /dev/ram0; \
  lvcreate -n my_lv -L 80M my_vg; \
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/my_vg/my_lv; \
  mount /dev/my_vg/my_lv /mnt/ramdisk'

ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'umount /mnt/ramdisk; \
  lvremove -yff /dev/my_vg/my_lv; \
  vgremove -yff my_vg; \
  wipefs /dev/ram0; \
  pvremove -yff /dev/ram0'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Updated Errors : output of `journalctl -xeu my_lvm.service`

```
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2881]:   Logical volume my_vg/my_lv contains a filesystem in use.
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2882]:   Logical volume my_vg/my_lv contains a filesystem in use.
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2883]: DEVICE OFFSET TYPE        UUID                                   LABEL
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2883]: ram0   0x218  LVM2_member nEmZLv-x6eJ-WnQV-JIpq-zbK5-EsXA-fEhFqM
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   WARNING: PV /dev/ram0 is used by VG my_vg.
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   WARNING: Wiping physical volume label from /dev/ram0 of volume group "my_vg".
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   Can't open /dev/ram0 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   Can't open /dev/ram0 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   Error opening device /dev/ram0 for reading at 0 length 4096.
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com bash[2878]:   Cannot use /dev/ram0: device has a signature
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com systemd[1]: my_lvm.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com systemd[1]: my_lvm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 14 15:05:40 server1.example.com systemd[1]: Stopped Create and mount LVM logical volume.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fulfill my requirement, it seems to work without any issue.Unless there is a better way to do it.

```
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/brd.conf
brd
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/brd.conf 
options brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=73400320 max_part=1
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ lsmod | grep brd
brd                    16384  1
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$
```

Unit file :

```
[Unit]
Description=Create and mount LVM logical volume

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'pvcreate /dev/ram0; \
  vgcreate my_vg /dev/ram0; \
  lvcreate --type vdo -n my_lv -l 17919 -V 700G  --config "allocation/vdo_slab_size_mb=1024" my_vg; \
  mkfs.ext4 -K /dev/my_vg/my_lv; \
  mount /dev/my_vg/my_lv /mnt/ramdisk; \
  lvmdevices -y --deldev /dev/ram0'


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```